# NHibernate + Multiple foreign keys to same column

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to map my `Team` and `Match` table by using following mappings:

// Team.cs

```
public class Team
{
    public virtual int ID { get; private set; }
    public virtual string TeamName { get; set; }
    public virtual Cup Cup { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Match> Matches { get; set; }

    public Team()
    {
        Matches = new List<Match>();
    }
}

public class TeamMap : ClassMap<Team>
{
    public TeamMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID);
        Map(x => x.TeamName).Not.Nullable();
        References(x => x.Cup, "CupID");

        HasMany(x => x.Matches)
            .Key(x => x.Columns.Add("Team1ID", "Team2ID"))
            .Inverse().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();

        Table("Teams");
    }
}
```

// Match.cs

```
public class Match
{
    public virtual int ID { get; private set; }
    public virtual Team Team1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Team Team2 { get; set; }
    public virtual int WinnerID { get; set; }
    public virtual Cup Cup { get; set; }
}

public class MatchMap : ClassMap<Match>
{
    public MatchMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID);
        Map(x => x.WinnerID);
        References(x => x.Team1, "Team1ID");
        References(x => x.Team2, "Team2ID");
        References(x => x.Cup, "CupID");
        Table("Matches");
    }
}
```

However, it throws an exception that says:

> Foreign key
>   (FKEFFCA4CA45169AED:Matches [Team1ID,
>   Team2ID])) must have same number of
>   columns as the referenced primary key
>   (Teams [ID])

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

I was able to solve it by mixing something together based on the comment wrote by @Yads.

My code:

// Team.cs

```
public class Team
{
    public virtual int ID { get; private set; }
    public virtual string TeamName { get; set; }
    public virtual Cup Cup { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Match> HomeMatches { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Match> AwayMatches { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Match> Matches { get { return HomeMatches.Concat(AwayMatches).ToList(); }}

    public Team()
    {
        HomeMatches = new List<Match>();
        AwayMatches = new List<Match>();
    }
}

public class TeamMap : ClassMap<Team>
{
    public TeamMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID);
        Map(x => x.TeamName).Not.Nullable();
        References(x => x.Cup, "CupID");

        HasMany(x => x.HomeMatches).KeyColumn("HomeTeamID")
            .Inverse().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();

        HasMany(x => x.AwayMatches).KeyColumn("AwayTeamID")
            .Inverse().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
        Table("Teams");
    }
}
```

// Match.cs

```
public class Match
{
    public virtual int ID { get; private set; }
    public virtual Team HomeTeam { get; set; }
    public virtual Team AwayTeam { get; set; }
    public virtual int WinnerID { get; set; }
    public virtual Cup Cup { get; set; }
}

public class MatchMap : ClassMap<Match>
{
    public MatchMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID);
        Map(x => x.WinnerID);
        References(x => x.HomeTeam, "HomeTeamID");
        References(x => x.AwayTeam, "AwayTeamID");
        References(x => x.Cup, "CupID");
        Table("Matches");
    }
}
```

However, I'm not aware of what drawbacks this approach have... The .Concat() seems a bit nasty to me...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571068/nhibernate-map-multiple-columns-into-a-single-collection

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but I feel like I've answered this exact question before...

The error you're seeing is occurring because you're creating an association based upon a composite inverse key, which won't be able to be mapped to a single foreign key.

One solution would be to try to shoehorn your "ideal" relational model into your object model, or, alternatively you could enrich your model. I suggest having a rich model to express a team playing in a match, you could call it `Participation`. This would give you a many to many relationship between teams and matches.

The downside to this is you would need to express the cardinality of the relationship as a business rule (so you can't have three teams playing in the same match).

The advantage is you could have a flag on the participation saying who the winner was, so that you don't need to have a `WinnerId` field on your object model.

You'd end up with code that would be used like this:

```
var match = new Match();
match.AddTeam(team1);
match.AddTeam(team2);

var winner = match.Participants.FindWinner();
winner = match.Winner; // alias for the above
```

Comment: @jonnii - That was the exact same approach I came up with at the very start! - However I found it wrong to have a many-to-many relationship between `Teams` and `Matches` since I knew that there will ALWAYS only be 2 Teams for a Match. I disscused this subject with @Cade Roux => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194433/sql-design-database-to-reflect-tournament-design

Comment: It's more flexible and there's nothing stopping you from having three teams in a match in the database, but the model is richer and more expressive. It'll also simplify your queries, for example imagine querying for `teams who have played 3 matches this year`. The model your suggesting isn't also inherently safe and requires validation, for example Team1 and Team2 can't be the same, and WinnerId needs to be one of Team1Id or Team2Id. I'd rather take the cardinality pain than the alternative.

Comment: @jonnii - I can easily find out who have played 3 matches this year: `cupEntity.Teams.Where(x => x.Matches.Date == somedata);` - Also see my updated post... I figured out how to get it working without many-to-many, however I'm not fully aware of the drawbacks of doing it that way..

Comment: @ebb there aren't really any drawbacks, except that your model is a bit wonky. I really think you should consider modelling the association.

Comment: @jonnii - But the association would be rather "useless" since I know the exact number of teams that will participate in a match... But yes you're right about that my model is a bit 'wonky'...

Comment: Because you want to indicate who won I think it makes sense to model the association. I think what you have now would be ok if you weren't.